# Kotlin Delegate with MultiDex on Android below 21

Tags: android, kotlin, android-multidex, kotlin-reflect, kotlin-delegate

I have the following Delegate...

```
fun integerPref(initialValue: Int) = object : ObservableProperty<Int>(initialValue) {

    override fun afterChange(property: KProperty<*>, oldValue: Int, newValue: Int) {
        getSharedPreference(INTEGER_PREF, EasyInjection.mode)
                .edit()
                .putInt(property.toString(), newValue)
                .apply()
    }

    override fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): Int {
        return getSharedPreference(INTEGER_PREF, EasyInjection.mode)
                .getInt(property.toString(), initialValue)
    }
}
```

This delegate aim to handling share preference. **The problem happen when my application become MultiDex**. When I use it like below code in activity, application crash.

```
class IntroduceActivity : BaseActivity() {

    private val CURRENT_VERSION = 1
    private val introVersion by integerPref()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_introduce)

        if (introVersion == CURRENT_VERSION) {
            finish()
        }
   }
}
```

But, if I change the code to this one. Application **not** crash

```
class IntroduceActivity : BaseActivity() {

    private val CURRENT_VERSION = 1

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_introduce)

        var introVersion by integerPref()
        if (introVersion == CURRENT_VERSION) {
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

I have read this document and it have some notice..

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

> Caution: Do not execute MultiDex.install() or any other code through
>   reflection or JNI before MultiDex.install() is complete. Multidex
>   tracing will not follow those calls, causing ClassNotFoundException or
>   verify errors due to a bad class partition between DEX files.

In conclusion, I want to know what happen in this scenario.

- application crash happen on Android below 21
- kotlin delegate use reflection
- why change from field variable to local variable is solved problem ?
- Logcat is not help

**Logcat**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.apg.mobile.som.uat/com.apg.mobile.som.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatApi23$SharedElementCallbackImpl not present
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompatApi23$SharedElementCallbackImpl not present
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredClasses(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredClasses(Class.java:534)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.structure.reflect.ReflectJavaClass.getInnerClassNames(ReflectJavaClass.kt:35)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.structure.reflect.ReflectJavaClass.getInnerClassNames(ReflectJavaClass.kt:27)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaClassMemberScope$nestedClassIndex$1.invoke(LazyJavaClassMemberScope.kt:617)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaClassMemberScope$nestedClassIndex$1.invoke(LazyJavaClassMemberScope.kt:64)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:323)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:370)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaClassMemberScope$nestedClasses$1.invoke(LazyJavaClassMemberScope.kt:626)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaClassMemberScope$nestedClasses$1.invoke(LazyJavaClassMemberScope.kt:64)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunction.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:408)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaClassMemberScope.getContributedClassifier(LazyJavaClassMemberScope.kt:651)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.scopes.InnerClassesScopeWrapper.getContributedClassifier(InnerClassesScopeWrapper.kt:29)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.jvm.JavaDescriptorResolver.resolveClass(JavaDescriptorResolver.kt:38)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.SingleModuleClassResolver.resolveClass(ModuleClassResolver.kt:29)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.types.JavaTypeResolver.computeTypeConstructor(JavaTypeResolver.kt:132)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.types.JavaTypeResolver.computeSimpleJavaClassifierType(JavaTypeResolver.kt:114)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.types.JavaTypeResolver.transformJavaClassifierType(JavaTypeResolver.kt:90)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.types.JavaTypeResolver.transformJavaType(JavaTypeResolver.kt:52)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.lazy.descriptors.LazyJavaClassDescriptor$LazyJavaClassTypeConstructor.computeSupertypes(LazyJavaClassDescriptor.kt:178)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.AbstractTypeConstructor$supertypes$1.invoke(AbstractTypeConstructor.kt:35)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.AbstractTypeConstructor$supertypes$1.invoke(AbstractTypeConstructor.kt:22)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:
```